# Why will C not launch a new shell?

Tags: c, security

I have a small chunk of C code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *name[2];

    name[0] = '/bin/sh';
    name[1] = NULL;
    execve(name[0], name, NULL);
}
```

I have a symlink sh -> zsh. When I run the program nothing happens and I stay in the same shell. I know I am not in a new shell since when i exit once the terminal exits. If i run `/bin/sh` I get another shell. Is my code wrong or is this some type of security measure not allowing me to do this?

Comment: Do basic error checking. Call `perror` after the `execve` call to see whether it is failing and why.

Comment: Compile with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`. That should fix this problem (once you fix your code to compile again). This fix works on incredibly large portion of novice C programmers' problems and bugs!

Comment: Why is this tagged _bash_?

Comment: @user1934428 updated. I was not sure if this was some type of security feature in bash / zsh. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling this with warnings immediately shows what's wrong:

```
gcc -g t.c
t.c: In function ‘main’:
t.c:7:15: warning: character constant too long for its type
    7 |     name[0] = '/bin/sh';
      |               ^~~~~~~~~
t.c:7:13: warning: assignment to ‘char *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
    7 |     name[0] = '/bin/sh';
      |             ^
t.c:9:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘execve’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    9 |     execve(name[0], name, NULL);
      |     ^~~~~~
```

*Of course* this program doesn't work. A string literal you want is `"/bin/sh"` (the kind of quotes you use *matters* in `C`).